# How to achieve guaranteed concurrency in service bus?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to achieve some guaranteed concurrency in function app which is subscribed to a service bus.

To achieve this, I've implemented partition in service bus.

If my message distribution in service bus is like this:

```
Partition1  Partition2  Partition3
message1    message3    mesaage5
message2    message4    message6
```

I expected my function app invocation serial to be :

```
message1 --> message3 -->message5 -->message2 -->message4-->message6
```

which is not happening.

My `host.json` configuration is

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this? By using sessionId or transaction?

Comment: It's spelled **achieve** - not "acheive" ...

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning is not intended for concurrency. Partitioning with Azure Service Bus is intended to ensure that in case some partitions are experiencing a problem, not all messages are not available but some.

Concurrency in your configuration is set to one. So you'll get messages from a random partition, processed one at a time. If you need a guaranteed order, that would be message sessions. Transactional processing is applicable for outgoing messages as a result of processing an incoming message.